# iPhone - Accessing the parent viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, parentviewcontroller

I have 2 viewcontrollers A, B

1. ViewController A is being displayed
   on the screen
2. The view of ViewController B is
   added to the view of ViewController
   A.

How can i access ViewController A from ViewController B without passing a pointer?

self.parentViewController does not work it returns nuil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work though its not very elegant:

```
UIViewController* viewControllerA = 
    (UIViewController*) [[self.view superview] nextResponder];
```

Comment: this returns a UINavigaionView, it doesn't return he view controller. I ended up passing the parent to child manually

Answer (score 1):

Why is the view of viewController B added to the view of viewController A? If you are meaning to add a view to viewController A, you can do that by allocating a new UIView and displaying that on top of the current view.

On the other hand if you are trying to transition from one view controller to another, i.e going from A to B and then back to A, you should use a UINavigationController as specified in the View Controller Programming Guide in the Apple Documentation.

Source: [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW10)

**EDIT**: If you want to use `[[self parentViewController] yourMethodHere];` you will need a view hierarchy, for which you can use the UINavigationController. In your current scheme there is no hierarchy built so there is no parent view controller.